# Php mysql search option

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently self studying PHP and right now, I'm trying to create a simple library system. And now, I'm having some trouble with the search option. I believe that my query and conditional statement are correct but I still can't show the output.

This are the codes:

```
    <html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <head>Home Page!</head>
<h1>List of Books</h1>

<?php include 'show.php'; ?>
<?php

require 'dbcon.php';
$Terror = $Aerror = $Derror = $Cerror = $matches = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$T = $_POST['title'];
$A = $_POST['Author'];
$D = $_POST['Desc'];
$C = $_POST['Category'];
$X = $_POST['Opt'];

$del_sql = "delete from a where Title = '".$T."' AND Author = '".$A."' ";
"delete from b where Title = '".$T."' AND Description = '".$D."' AND Category = '".$C."' "; 

    if($X == 'Add'){
    $in_sql = "insert a (Title, Author) values ('".$T."', '".$A."'); insert b (Title, Description, Category) values ('".$T."', '".$D."', '".$C."')";
        if(empty($T) || empty($A) || empty($D) || empty($C)){
        if(empty($A)) $Aerror = "Fill up Author";
        if(empty($T)) $Terror = "Fill up Title";
        if(empty($D)) $Derror = "Fill up Description";
        if(empty($C)) $Cerror = "Fill up Category";
        }
        else if(mysqli_multi_query($dbcon, $in_sql)){
        echo "New recored added";
        }
    }
    else if ($X == 'Del'){
        if (mysqli_multi_query($dbcon, $del_sql)){
        echo "Record deleted";
        }
    }

    else if ($X == 'Search'){
        $sea1_sql = "select count(Title) from a where Title = '".$T."'";
        $sea_sql = mysqli_multi_query($dbcon, "select * from a where Title = '".$T."' AND Author = '".$A."'");
                    "select Description, Category from b where Title = '".$T."' AND Description = '".$D."' AND Category = '".$C."'";
        if (mysqli_query($dbcon, $sea1_sql) > 0){           
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sea_sql)){
                echo "<table class = fix>";
                echo "<tr><th>Title</th> <th> ". $row['Title'] . " </th></tr>";
                echo "<tr><th>Author </th> <th> ". $row['Author'] . " </th></tr>";
                echo "<tr><th>Description </th> <th> ". $row['Description'] . " </th></tr>";
                echo "<tr><th>Category </th> <th> ". $row['Category'] . " </th></tr>";
                echo "</table><br>";
            }
        }
            else if (mysqli_query($dbcon, $sea1_sql) < 0){
                echo "Can't find data!";
            }
        }

    }

    ?>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <br>Title: <input type="text" name="title"> <?php echo $Terror; ?><br>
            Author: <input type="text" name="Author"><?php echo $Aerror; ?><br>
            Description: <input type="text" name="Desc"><?php echo $Derror; ?><br>
            Category: <input type="text" name="Category"><?php echo $Cerror; ?><br>
        <select name="Opt">
        <option disabled selected>N/A</option>
        <option value='Add'>Add</option>
        <option value='Edit'>Edit</option>
        <option value='Del'>Del</option>

    <option value='Search'>Search</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">



    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I've seen lots of questions where people have problems using `mysqli_multi_query`. I suggest you use separate calls to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Please use more meaningful table names than `a` and `b`.

Comment: I don't understand your second query in `Search`. Why are you selecting `Description` and `Category` when you know that they have to be equal to `$D` and `$C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if (mysqli_query($dbcon, $sea1_sql) > 0){
```

`myqli_query()` doesn't return the value of `count(Title)`. You need to fetch the row.

```
$sea1_result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sea1_sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sea1_result);
if ($row['count(Title)'] > 0) {
```

You're also using `mysqli_multi_query()` incorrectly. It doesn't return a `mysqli_result` object that you can fetch results from, it returns a boolean that indicates whether the first query was successful or got an error. You need to call [`mysqli_use_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) to get the results of each query, and then call `mysqli_fetch_array()` on this.

But it looks like you shouldn't be using `mysqli_multi_query()` at all. You want to get the rows from `a` and `b` for the same title together, not all `a` rows before all `b` rows. You should join the two tables:

```
$sea_result = mysqli_query("SELECT a.*, b.Description, b.Category
                            FROM a JOIN b ON a.Title = b.Title
                            WHERE a.Title = '$T' AND a.Author = 'A'
                            AND b.Description = '$D' AND b.Category = '$C'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful answer. Not only you answer my question but you also enlightened me on how to use some of the commands correctly. I'm still trying to familiarize myself with mysqli commands. Thanks again!